# How to set QTableWidget cell background color when table unfocused?

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a Qt based application with multiple QTableWidget tables. 
My usage scenario:

1. I click a cell inside first table; focus is moved to the clicked cell;
2. I click a cell inside second table; focus is moved to the clicked cell/table.

Now I would like to set the background color of the cell inside the first table which is now unfocused, how can I do that?

**Qt version=4.8.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eventFilter` or subclass `QTableWidget`. If you get focus on some `tableWidget` - reset `stylesheet`, if you get focus out - apply special `stylesheet` (example in code)

For example:

```
{
//somewhere in constructor 
string = ui->tableWidget_2->styleSheet();//save normal stylesheet
}


bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == ui->tableWidget_2 && event->type()==QEvent::FocusIn)
        ui->tableWidget_2->setStyleSheet(string);//or set just " "
    if(obj == ui->tableWidget_2 && event->type()==QEvent::FocusOut)
        ui->tableWidget_2->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item{background-color: red;}");

return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

In header:

```
protected:

     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private:
     QString string;
```

As you can see, with `stylesheet` you can customize your cells, so you can do much more than changing background color, of course, if you want this.